# ‘Remove wiki’ showing when a question is not a wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, community-wiki

While viewing [this non-wiki post](https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com/q/75/149), I noticed something strange in the mod-menu:

[image]

I tested this on other questions, but it only happens on this one.

Note: The post does have a wiki answer and selecting *remove wiki* does nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Remove wiki` button is used to remove wiki status from the current question and/or all answers that have wiki status. However, the label of the button did not make this clear.

The following changes have been made:

1. When the question has wiki and at least one answer has wiki, the label will say: "Remove wiki from question (and optionally from answers)". After clicking on the radio button, a secondary checkbox appears (now defaulting to `checked`) that gives the option to also remove wiki status from all answers.
2. When the question has wiki and no answers have wiki, the label will say: "Remove wiki" (note: this is not normally possible, but just in case, want to have it covered)
3. When the question does not have wiki, at least one answer has wiki, the label will say: "Remove wiki from answers". After clicking on the radio button, a secondary checkbox appears (now defaulting to `checked`) that gives the option to also remove wiki status from all answers. This secondary box *cannot* be unchecked (since otherwise what is the point?).

---

> mod remove wiki
> label lacked proper context
> more detail added

Answer (score 5):

> The post does have a wiki answer and selecting remove wiki does nothing

Pretty sure this is the bug: you're supposed to be presented with an option to apply the change to all answers upon selecting the radio button.