# Can't use Stacks editor for long posts on iOS because the cursor disappears

Tags: bug, ios, stacks-editor

When I try to edit text towards the end of a long post (or sometimes middle, for very long posts), my cursor disappears. Where exactly this happens seems to depend on where the scroll bar is.

I can't see where I'm typing except that text appears (or disappears, when backspacing), and trying to move around my cursor is hopeless because tapping doesn't make it appear and neither does holding the spacebar. I can't see if I have any text selected either (as I sometimes end up deleting the entire body of the post). Examples of a few answers where this happened:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/323179)
- [Allow 'improve' for Tag Wiki Edit Suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96233/323179)
- [New tags page mangles tag wiki excerpts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82702/323179)
- [‘Remove wiki’ showing when a question is not a wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366708/323179)
- My answer about [tables and accessibility](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418553/6083675), which isn't even that long or complicated.
- [Another answer of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380286/323179), which only uses bullets and a horizontal rule for formatting and also isn't really that long

Cursor is between *community* and the period when I was backspacing:

[image: cursor missing from CW FAQ answer]

I tested it on two different browsers (iOS Chrome and iOS Safari) on different devices and it happens on both. It also happens on the [preview editor](https://editor.stackoverflow.design/). (I have not encountered this on desktop, which is the device I have to switch to in order to make edits.) It doesn't happen on every answer, only when the answer is long or maybe has some complicated formatting. It also seems to happen in both editor modes.

Significantly, this is preventing me from editing something on a private Team (where this is the only editor, and I also see this happening on questions), so it should be fixed.

Comment: Can you add a gif showing what this looks like?

Comment: Have you only experienced this in iOS? Or on other operating systems/platforms as well?

Comment: @V2Blast It's only been on iOS but it's severe enough that it prevents me from editing a bunch of my answers.

Comment: This might be worth adding as a bug report on the [Beta release post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release/).